How to use shared external variables in `rust_socketio` (async version)?
Using the regular version works
use rust_socketio::{ClientBuilder, Payload, RawClient};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<String>();
    let tx_clone = tx.clone();
    let callback = move |payload: Payload, socket: RawClient| {
        tx_clone.send("...".to_string());
    };
    let callback2 = move |payload: Payload, socket: RawClient| {
        tx.send("...".to_string());
    };
    let socket = ClientBuilder::new("")
        .on("evt1", callback)
        .on("evt2", callback2)
        .connect()
        .expect("Connection failed");
}

but if I switch to use the async version
use rust_socketio::{
    asynchronous::{Client, ClientBuilder},
    Payload,
};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<String>();
    let tx_clone = tx.clone();
    let callback = |payload: Payload, socket: Client| {
        async move {
            tx_clone.send("...".to_string());
        }.boxed()
    };
    let callback2 = |payload: Payload, socket: Client| {
        async move {
            tx.send("...".to_string());
        }.boxed()
    };
    let socket = ClientBuilder::new("")
        .on("evt1", callback)
        .on("evt2", callback2)
        .connect()
        .await
        .expect("Connection failed");
}

Using the Async version I always get error:
expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `FnMut`

Couldn't figure out how to fix this. Also could not find examples on this.
All examples I could find are the simplest where callback doesn't need to access external variables.
Here is the .on() function.
 pub fn on<T: Into<Event>, F>(mut self, event: T, callback: F) -> Self
    where
        F: for<'a> std::ops::FnMut(Payload, Client) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()>
            + 'static
            + Send
            + Sync,
    {
        self.on
            .insert(event.into(), Callback::<DynAsyncCallback>::new(callback));
        self
    }



Here is an explanation what trait a closure implements does that help? Particularly you can't move tx_clone out of a closure and expect to be able to call it multiple times.

So it's impossible to use some external variable within the callbacks?

No, you just can't move it (as you do by using an async move block) and expect to reuse it. Just like with regular code.

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<String>();
    let tx2 = tx.clone();
    let socket = ClientBuilder::new("http://localhost:9559")
        .on("evt1", move |payload, socket| {
            let tx = tx.clone();
            async move {
                tx.send(format!("identity: {:?}", payload)).unwrap();
            }
            .boxed()
        })
        // .on("evt1", callback2)
        .on_any(move |evt, payload, socket| {
            let tx = tx2.clone();
            async move {
                tx.send(format!("{:?}", payload)).unwrap();
            }
            .boxed()
        })
        .connect()
        .await
        .expect("Connection failed");
}


